# Why does $n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k\;e^{k-2}} \implies n = \frac{2\;e^3}{2\;e-1}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

Consider $$n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k\;e^{k-2}}$$

Why does

$$n = \frac{2\;e^3}{2\;e-1}\;\;?$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:
$$n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k\;e^{k-2}}=e^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(2e)^k}$$

Observe that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(2e)^k}$ is an [Infinite Geometric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Infinite_geometric_series) with the first term $\frac1{(2e)^0}=1$ and common ratio $\frac1{2e}$ which lies $\in(0,1)$

Comment: Thank you very much for a short and concise answer! Cheers!

Comment: @JohnWO, my pleasure.